# Entering if (undefined) block

Tags: javascript, node.js, cloud9-ide

Im was trying to understand why this piece of code entering an if statement block when the condition is undefined as shown in this pictures:[image][image]

When    `console.log(err, typeof err)`    before the    `if(err)`    statement the output is:

```
> { [MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index: db_development.tempusers.$phoneNumber_1 dup key: { : "+972544637999" }]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'E11000 duplicate key error index: db_development.tempusers.$phoneNumber_1 dup key: { : "+972544637999" }',
  driver: true,
  code: 11000,
  index: 0,
  errmsg: 'E11000 duplicate key error index: db_development.tempusers.$phoneNumber_1 dup key: { : "+972544637999" }',
  getOperation: [Function],
  toJSON: [Function],
  toString: [Function] } 'object'
```

Which makes it very clear that err is not undefined as the debugger suggests, the problem is that for my understanding it can't be a problem in the debugger if it consist without it, when I run this node server in a docker container. Further more, on the client side code I receive the error when passing http request to my server, but it shows as undefined as well:[image]

Please help me figure this out, thanks.

Comment: *"When  console.log(err, typeof err) before the  if(err) statement the output is:"* Show that actual code.

Comment: *"Further more, on the client side code I receive the error when passing http request to my server, but it shows as undefined as well:"* Yes, but there's no `if (err)` there, so it's perfectly valid that `err` could be `undefined`.

Comment: As several of us said on your previous version of this question, it's simply impossible for `err` to actually be `undefined`. The fact that your `console.log` is showing that it isn't means that the title of this question is completely misleading: `err` is **not** undefined, it's a MongoError. The debugger doesn't understand that somehow, but that's the case. Fundamentally, you need to ditch the debugger you're using and use something else, at a minimum to eliminate it as a cause.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i know its perfectly valid on the client side, but the logic of my code is to check the status, and idintify that very same error that means the phonenumber is allready exist. I cant preform that chack if the response is undefined, correct me please if im wrong.

Comment: I don't know what's going on in that debugging session, other than (as I said earlier) it certainly looks like the debugger has been confused by something, possibly by a V8 optimization. There is no way, at all, that V8 will enter the `if` block if the condition is `if (err)` and `err` is `undefined`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Im wrong to assume it has nothing to do with the debugger if the problem still exist when I run the code in a container? there is no debugger there amd Im getting the very same behavior.

Comment: I know it's not the problem you are discussing with T.J., but have you tried changing `if (err)` with `if (typeof err !== "undefined")` just to see if the same error shows up?

Comment: As @T.J.Crowder suggested in your old question: Why don't you put another `console.log()` statement inside of your `if (err) {}` and inside of your `else {}` block, and then run it without the debugger or at least don't look at the debugger but at the `console` output. You will realize that if `err` is undefined the log in the `else` block will trigger and the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in cloud9 debugger, you should contact cloud9 support (see support menu in the ide) and show them the code that produces this error